# On how to make a Visual Studio Template that exports from SVN, runs some code gen, etc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, automation, boilerplate

I've not written a template or starter-kit for Visual Studio, so I'm not really sure which is the most appropriate for doing what I need, or if I need something even more general/powerful.

What I want to do is have a template project that exports some boiler plate code from subversion, installs some typical/required Nuget packages, imports that newly created project into svn, run some PowerShell scripts, etc.

Is this possible with either a template or starter-kit or is this maybe something that will require an entire add-on?

Comment: Do you mean *import* some boiler plate code from an svn repository? I don't understand what you'd be exporting since it sounds like you are talking about creating a brand new solution.

Comment: Right export from the svn some template code found there, then re-import into a new location the newly created project.

Comment: OK, I think you have your usage of import and export backwards. You want to ***import*** code from an svn repository or branch and then ***commit*** your *new* solution to a *new* repository or branch. I think if you make that change you might get more people looking at your question. It'll be easier to understand what you are asking and maybe not so scary.